# In-App Subscription Tiers?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am researching in-app purchase viability in my app and have some queries.

Is it possible to have a multi -tiered subscription model with in-app purchase on iOS?

E.g. 4.99 for Basic, 9.99 for Advanced.

I would need the user to be able to change tier as and when they wanted, just as you would expect from any subscription service.

Is that possible? Does Apple support this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible by opting out of the current subscription and then buying the Advanced Tier.

https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/In-App-Purchase-Guidelines.pdf

*Subscriptions and subscription renewals to content or services can be offered to customers for purchase.
!Renewal of an Auto-Renewing Subscription is handled automatically by the App Store. The user will be reminded shortly before their subscription is about to renew and all the billing is handled automatically by the App Store. Users can easily change their renewal frequency and **can opt-out of the renewal by turning off the Auto-Renew switch at least 24 hours before the end of the current subscription period.***

Comment: The problem with that with respect to the OP's question is that this makes the "when they [the customers] wanted" into "at the end of the subscription term". Functional? Yes, as long as your subscription duration is short (1 week, 1 month), but doesn't achieve the stated intent when the duration is 6 months or 1 year. Apple's solution isn't clean/user-friendly for bouncing back and forth between durations or SKUs that represent levels.